# Plotly table with multicolumns, with different amount of columns per level

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I can make a decent plotly table with the following code.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = np.random.randint(0,10,(4,5))

headers = [
            ["Year 1", "Foo"], 
            ["",       "Bar"],
            ["Year 2", "Foo"],
            ["",       "Bar"],
]


fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(values=headers),
    cells=dict(values=data)
)])
fig.show()
```

[image]

As can be seen on the image, now the first and second header both have four columns, with two of the top header simply being empty. My intention is to have the top header contain only two columns, with the second header containing four columns. How can this be achieved?